# The button that I created isn't working

Tags: javascript

The button that I created isn't working and I'm sure I did all the steps correctly.

I want to make a start screen that can proceed into a level option screen. But for starters, the button isn't working properly. I've already tried adding `println("20");` just to test if the button actually worked and it did but when I tried adding what I originally intended to add, nothing worked.

```
var f = createFont('calibri');
var gameScene;
var startScreen = function() {
  gameScene = 1;
  stroke(224, 224, 224);
  fill(0, 242, 255);
  rect(200, 200, 100, 100);

  stroke(255, 255, 255);
  line(300, 300, 200, 200);
  line(200, 300, 300, 200);
  //starts
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rotate(45);
  textFont(f, 20);
  text("Start", 360, -2);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  rotate(-89);
  text("start", 10, 350);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rotate(180);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text("Start", 1, -357);
  rotate(-270);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  text("Start", -350,3);
};
var gameScene1 = function(x, y) {
  gameScene = 2;
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(x, y, 20, 20);
};

startScreen();
mouseClicked = function() {
  if(mousePressed && mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 250 && mouseY < 350) {
    gameScene = 2;
};
```

Comment: i don't see a button. Also what's the context of your code? it looks like you're interacting with a canvas, but we don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or codepen of this? Btw you are missing `var` in front of `mouseClicked = function`